# Why does Firestore cloud function update data operation overwrite entire document?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I deployed the following cloud function in TypeScript to update a single field in a Firestore document using `update()`, which, as far as I understand, is only supposed to update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document. However, this cloud function overwrote the entire document.

```
export const userDidSignOut = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userId = data.userId
    const userSettingsUpdate = {
        private: {
            fcmToken: null
        }
    }

    admin.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(userId).update(userSettingsUpdate).then((result) => {
        console.log("DONE", result.writeTime.toDate)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR", error)
    })
})
```

1. Is this how update works in cloud functions?
2. What is the proper way to update fields in cloud functions?
3. Does `then()` return a result only if the write succeeded?

Before and after:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document contents both before and after this code runs.  There should be no question as to what exactly happened when you run this code.  Code running in Cloud Functions does not generally behave differently than in other contexts - it is still just running JavaScript in a node environment.

Comment: Also consider that you're not returning anything to the client app.  You should return a promise that resolves with the object to be serialized as JSON and sent to the caller.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'll put together some screenshots in a moment but are you saying that the document was not supposed to be overwritten?

Comment: @DougStevenson screenshots added

Comment: I don't know what's supposed to happen here, since I can't see the contents of the document that's being updated (nor can I see that it's modifying the expected document, since I don't know the value of `userId`).  I suggest providing more complete information (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: The update is working as expected - you are telling it to overwrite the "private" property of the document in its entirety.  If that's not what you want, use dot notation to call out the nested property to update, separately from the other nested properties.

Comment: @DougStevenson what a silly oversight; I overlooked that the entire document is wrapped in a map. One last thing, does `then()` return a result only if the write succeeds and is caught by the error handler if it doesn't?

Comment: That's the way all promises work in JavaScript - they only become fulfilled on success.